# Efficiently extracting pairwise correlations in R

Tags: r, iteration, reliability

This seems like it should be straightforward but I have a data frame and need to extract the correlation of the scores for each possible pair of `id` across `trial` (in other words, compare score of id 1 on trial 10 to id 2 on trial 10, id 1 on trial 10 to id 3 on trial 10, and so on. An example data frame is as follows.

```
id <- c('1','1','1','2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3')
trial <- c('10','11','12','10', '11', '12', '10', '11', '12')
score<- c('634', '981','101', '621', '31', '124', '827', '404', '92')
d <- data.frame(id, trial, score)
```

> d

```
 id trial score
  1    10   634
  1    11   981
  1    12   101
  2    10   621
  2    11    31
  2    12   124
  3    10   827
  3    11   404
  3    12    92
```

The result should be a new matrix with correlations of all possible combinations. Ostensibly it's for evaluating score reliability across ids.

The data is about 10000 lines long which causes R to choke up. I've looked in the forums here and tried to figure it out using `comb` or `outer` but got confused by the syntax. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Roland's idea, but using R base function `xtabs`

```
> d$score <- as.numeric(as.character(d$score))
> cor(xtabs(score ~ trial + id, data=d))
            1           2         3
1  1.00000000 -0.02568439 0.5295394
2 -0.02568439  1.00000000 0.8344046
3  0.52953942  0.83440458 1.0000000
```

Comment: Never used xtabs before, this seems very handy!

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this could be by using data.table. You can use the following

```
library(data.table)
d.t <- data.table(d)
setkey(d.t,"trial","id")
```

And then something like this should help.

```
temp <- cor(as.vector(d.t[J("10","1")]$score),as.vector(d.t[J("10","2")]$score))
```

Post this could put a loop around this or use sapply and then rbind the results into a matrix/data frame

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too many ids, I would reshape the data here and use that `cor` accepts a data.frame as input:

```
d$score <- as.numeric(as.character(d$score))
library(reshape2)
d1 <- dcast(d,trial~id)
cor(d1[,-1])
#            1           2         3
#1  1.00000000 -0.02568439 0.5295394
#2 -0.02568439  1.00000000 0.8344046
#3  0.52953942  0.83440458 1.0000000
```